# Panalphebetic strings provable by DFA?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

Is the language of panalphabetic strings decidable by DFA? If so, how can I prove it?

A string {a,…,z}* is said to be panalphabetic if it contains at least one occurrence of each letter.

Comment: That's the language consisting of all strings that use all letters of the alphabet?

Comment: A string {a,…,z}* is said to be panalphabetic if it contains at least one occurrence of each letter.

Comment: Start by looking at smaller alphabets, say $\{a,b\}$, then $\{a,b,c\}$, perhaps $\{a,b,c,d\}$. You'll probably see a pattern.

Comment: @Varoag please edit your question and add there the definition you stated in comments.